# Is there any relation between variance and gradients in image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was working on blemish removal in Python. For reference on how to implement blemish removal, I have gone through this code: [Blemish Removal](https://github.com/pgrudzien12/opencv-exercises/blob/master/blemish-removal/submission.py). The steps needed to achieve blemish removal is:

1. Find the coordinates (i.e coordinates of the pixel) where there is a blemish
2. Once you have the coordinates, next find the neighboring coordinates where the gradient is low.
   The idea behind this step is find a patch which is smooth and apply on the area where there is blemish otherwise know as patch.
3. Then apply seamless cloning to apply the patch.

Now, the code below uses the Scharr operator in OpenCV to calculate gradients. Next it sums the absolute gradients in both x-direction and y-direction. These total gradients calculated are for a particular patch.

```
def calcVariance(patch):
    x = cv2.Scharr(patch, -1, 1, 0)
    y = cv2.Scharr(patch, -1, 0, 1)

    return np.abs(x) + np.abs(y)
```

From the code below, look at the line `variance = 1/calcVariance(patch).sum()`. We are setting variance equal to inverse of gradients. I am bit confused at this particular line. Why are we doing this?  Again why is it sum is calculated again `calcVariance(patch).sum()` ?.

```
def pickBestAround(xy, values, image):
    bestV = 0
    best_xy = None
    for move in np.array([(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]) * 30:
        xy_m = xy + move
        if xy_m[xy_m<0].sum() < 0:
            continue
        patch = getPatch(xy_m, values)
        variance = 1/calcVariance(patch).sum()
        if variance > bestV:
            bestV = variance
            best_xy = xy_m

        return getPatch(best_xy, values), getPatch(best_xy, image)
```

I infer from the code that **variance is inversely proportional to gradients** calculated. Is that true?

Comment: "variance" might be an unluckily named variable. The author might assign an alternative meaning to it. Gradients are certainly unrelated to the mathematical definition of "variance".

Comment: If that's the case, why the author is taking the inverse of gradients. Any thoughts on that ? @CrisLuengo

Comment: The image patch returned by `calcVariance` has higher values where there are more edges. Apply `.sum()` to that to get a single value that is larger where there are more edges. The inverse will be larger where there are fewer edges. The code is looking for a uniform patch, the patch with fewest edges.